# SQL 2022 replication does not work on non-standard port

Tags: replication, availability-groups, sql-server-2022

Consider the following:

```
3 identical Windows Server 2019 VMs running WSFC (no shared storage)
3 SQL 2022 PROD instances across those 3 VMs (using WSFC/AG for easy hostname, three instance AG)
1 SQL 2022 DEV instance on the second (using WSFC/AG for easy hostname, single instance AG)
1 SQL 2022 TST instance on the third (using WSFC/AG for easy hostname, single instance AG)

VM1:
MSSQL.domain.com:1433
MSSQL01\MSSQLSERVER:1533 (primary)

VM2:
MSSQLDEV.domain.com:1433
MSSQL02\MSSQLSERVER:1533 (sync replica)
MSSQL02\MSSQLDEV:1633

VM1:
MSSQLTST.domain.com:1433
MSSQL03\MSSQLSERVER:1533 (async replica)
MSSQL03\MSSQLTST:1733
```

As you can see each of my AG is listening on SQL standard port `1433` and each underlying instance is listening on a custom port (`PRD 1533, DEV 1533, TST 1733`).

Now connecting to the shared hostname works fine across the board and connecting to each instances works in SSMS (or sqlcmd) if I specify the port.

However replication will not connect to specific instance, nor will it use the shared hostnames. Here is how I setup distribution and publishers:

```
:Connect MSSQLDEV.domain.com
USE master
EXEC sp_adddistributor @distributor = N'MSSQL02\MSSQLDEV', @password = N'StrongPlaceholderPassword';
EXEC sp_adddistributiondb @database = N'distribution', @security_mode = 1;
EXEC sys.sp_adddistpublisher @publisher = N'MSSQL.domain.com', @distribution_db = N'distribution', @working_directory = N'\\domain.com\sql\replication$';
EXEC sys.sp_adddistpublisher @publisher = N'MSSQL01.domain.com,1533', @distribution_db = N'distribution', @working_directory = N'\\domain.com\sql\replication$';
EXEC sys.sp_adddistpublisher @publisher = N'MSSQL02.domain.com,1533', @distribution_db = N'distribution', @working_directory = N'\\domain.com\sql\replication$';
EXEC sys.sp_adddistpublisher @publisher = N'MSSQL03.domain.com,1533', @distribution_db = N'distribution', @working_directory = N'\\domain.com\sql\replication$';

:Connect MSSQL01.domain.com,1533
USE master
EXEC sys.sp_adddistributor @distributor = N'MSSQL02\MSSQLDEV', @password = N'StrongPlaceholderPassword';

:Connect MSSQL02.domain.com,1533
USE master
EXEC sys.sp_adddistributor @distributor = N'MSSQL02\MSSQLDEV', @password = N'StrongPlaceholderPassword';

:Connect MSSQL03.domain.com,1533
USE master
EXEC sys.sp_adddistributor @distributor = N'MSSQL02\MSSQLDEV', @password = N'StrongPlaceholderPassword';
```

So distribution is configured on `MSSQLDEV` and each PRD instance will be defined as publisher for resilience. I'm ok with distribution DB being a SPOF.

The `sp_adddistributor` stored procedure requires the publishers hostname on `MSSQLDEV` to match the `@@SERVERNAME` or it'll try to connect to a remote host (see line 205 of SP). So no `MSSQLDEV.domain.com` possible here.

The sp_adddistpublisher stored procedure requires each publisher to match the same rule or adding the publisher will fail (not listed as publisher on distributor). The `MSSQL.domain.com` hostname will work in SSMS if connected to it while adding publisher. However I wont be able to replicas (at least not without failing over the AG).

So the distribution and publisher creation script works but as soon as I create a publication on a PRD instance, the agent fails to start with a connectivity error:

```
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
Stack:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ServerConnectionEmulator.Connect()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.EstablishPublisherConnection()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotProvider.GenerateSnapshot()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.SnapshotGenerationAgent.InternalRun()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.AgentCore.Run() (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 5)
Get help: http://help/5
Server , Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 5)
Get help: http://help/5
Source: 
Target Site: 
Message: Access is denied
Stack:  (Source: <Unknown>, Error number: 0)
Get help: http://help/0
```

[image: Replication agent failing to start]

When I capture network traffic I can see it doesn't use the specified port to connect. So this failure is expected (`MSSQL01` isn't listening on `1433` but on `1533`, nor is `MSSQL02\MSSQLDEV` on port `1433`)

I've tried to adjust the publication job agent parameters from:

```
-Publisher [MSSQL-01-M] -PublisherDB [BenTestZone] -Distributor [MSSQL-02-M\MSSQLDEV] -Publication [BenTestZone] -DistributorSecurityMode 1
```

To:

```
-Publisher [MSSQL-01-M,1533] -PublisherDB [BenTestZone] -Distributor [MSSQL-02-M\MSSQLDEV,1633] -Publication [BenTestZone] -DistributorSecurityMode 1
```

But then I get error `The snapshot could not be generated because the publisher is inactive.` which is an error you'd get if the server names don't match...

I found [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-replication-non-default-ports?view=sql-server-ver16) that make me think it's a supported feature but no Linux in my setup (but why would it just work in Linux?). Also workarounds like [this one](https://www.dcac.com/sql/sql-server/sql-server-replication-publishers-and-non-standard-sql-server-ports/) don't seem to work in SQL 2022 anymore.

What am I doing wrong? Can I get this working? I can always load a backup daily using a task scheduler script to mimic snapshot replication but my devs would like transactional and merge replication on certain databases.

My last option would be to "fork" those replication SPs and create my own to overcome the naming limitation. But that's probably not a great idea nor is it supported by Microsoft.

And ChatGPT was of no help here! It suggested aliases but that's [not supported anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16) in 2022.